# scalpel - error when running ./configure

Tags: configure, computer-forensics

I've downloaded scalpel from [github](https://github.com/sleuthkit/scalpel) and ran

```
./configure
```

but I get the following error:

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `Makefile.in
```

I've no idea what this means, I am missing some dependency or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run ./bootstrap first.  We just removed the configure script.  It was checked in by mistake.

See also: https://github.com/sleuthkit/scalpel/issues/2

Comment: awesome - I was reading the wrong readme, hadnt noticed these issues, thanks!